# How to submit hadoop jobs as other Linux users

Tags: hadoop

user "hadoop" is runnnig jobtracker and tasktracker on cluster, but what if other Linux users want to submit their jobs?

I've followed this documentation, http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/service_level_auth.html#Hadoop+Services+and+Configuration+Properties
add following into "core-site.xml":

```
    <property>
            <name>hadoop.security.authorization</name>
            <value>true</value>
    </property>
```

and for conf file "hadoop-policy.xml", I add "hadoopGroup" to "security.job.submission.protocol.acl", my account "qingya.shu" belong to this group.
but when i run hadoop as qingya.shu, encountered error like:

```
12/11/09 12:57:29 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
12/11/09 12:57:29 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
12/11/09 12:57:29 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
12/11/09 12:57:29 INFO mapred.JobClient: Cleaning up the staging area file:/lustre/hadoop/user/qingya.shu/.staging/job_201211082024_0008
12/11/09 12:57:29 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:qingya.shu cause:org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/lustre/hadoop/user/qingya.shu/.staging/job_201211082024_0008/job.xml does not exist.
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.submitJob(JobTracker.java:3943)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:563)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1388)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1384)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1382)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/lustre/hadoop/user/qingya.shu/.staging/job_201211082024_0008/job.xml does not exist.
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:397)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:251)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress.<init>(JobInProgress.java:406)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.submitJob(JobTracker.java:3941)
    ... 11 more

org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/lustre/hadoop/user/qingya.shu/.staging/job_201211082024_0008/job.xml does not exist.
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.submitJob(JobTracker.java:3943)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:563)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1388)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1384)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1382)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/lustre/hadoop/user/qingya.shu/.staging/job_201211082024_0008/job.xml does not exist.
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:397)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:251)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress.<init>(JobInProgress.java:406)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.submitJob(JobTracker.java:3941)
    ... 11 more

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1070)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:225)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.$Proxy1.submitJob(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:921)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:850)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:850)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:500)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:530)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:68)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
```

notice that lustre is used as distributed file system instead of HDFS.

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```xml
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.security.authorization</name>
    <value>simple</value>
  </property>
```